# I writng custom Agile Tab for JIRA server 7.0.2 with JIRA Agile 6.7.11

Tags: jira

I writng custom Agile Tab for JIRA server 7.0.2 with JIRA Agile 6.7.11.

That I want list all Spitns to this Tab.

StringBuffer outputProjects = new StringBuffer();

```
    ServiceOutcome<Collection<Sprint>> allsprints = sprintManager.getAllSprints();

    Collection<Sprint> allsprintscollection = allsprints.getValue();

    outputProjects.append("");

    for (Iterator<Sprint> iterator = allsprintscollection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) { 
         Sprint sprint = iterator.next();
         outputProjects.append("<tr>");
         outputProjects.append("<td>"+sprint.getName()+"</td>");
         outputProjects.append("<td>"+sprint.getId()+"</td>");
         outputProjects.append("<td></td>");
         outputProjects.append("<td></td>");
         outputProjects.append("<td></td>");
         outputProjects.append("</tr>");
    }

     Plugin plugin = pluginAccesor.getEnabledPlugin("com.i4ware.plugin.timesheet.timesheet");
    PluginInformation pluginInformation = plugin.getPluginInformation();
    String version = pluginInformation.getVersion();

    tmpParams.put("sprintsHtml", outputProjects.toString());
    tmpParams.put("project", context.getProject().getKey());
    tmpParams.put("baseUrl",applicationProperties.getBaseUrl());
    tmpParams.put("version",version);

    return descriptor.getHtml("view",tmpParams);
```

But I got with error message log file:

```
2015-12-02 10:31:55,455 http-nio-8181-exec-12 WARN admin 631x1578x1 xhcbd 80.222.144.149,37.48.78.137 /projects/AD [c.atlassian.ozymandias.SafePluginPointAccess] Unable to run plugin code because of 'java.lang.NullPointerException - null'.
```

Comment: Have u looked at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/java.lang.NullPointerException+While+Accessing+Notifications+Tab+of+Projects ?

Comment: I am looked from there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution my self by help of Atlassian Developer Community.

Class:

```
import com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.SprintManager;
```

Is a privete so it must be loeded first like this:

```
import com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.SprintManager; 
import com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint; 
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor; 
import com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.ServiceOutcome; 
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext; 
import org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException; 
import com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.OsgiContainerManager; 
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle; 
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext; 
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference; 
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils; 
import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate; 
import com.atlassian.greenhopper.web.rapid.view.JqlHelper; 

public class LoadSprintsForGanttServlet extends HttpServlet 
{

private String jqlQuery; 
 
private SprintManager getSprintManager() throws InvalidSyntaxException { 
      
ApplicationContext appCtx = (ApplicationContext) getGreenHopperAppCtx(); 
    if ( appCtx !=null ) { 
        return (SprintManager) appCtx.getBean( "sprintManagerImpl" ); 
    } 
    return null; 
}
 
private JqlHelper getJqlHelper() throws InvalidSyntaxException { 
      
ApplicationContext appCtx = (ApplicationContext) getGreenHopperAppCtx(); 
    if ( appCtx !=null ) { 
        return (JqlHelper) appCtx.getBean( "jqlHelper" ); 
    } 
    return null; 
} 
 
private Object getGreenHopperAppCtx() throws InvalidSyntaxException { 
OsgiContainerManager osgi = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(OsgiContainerManager.class); 
    if ( osgi==null ) { 
         java.lang.System.out.println("OSGI Not Found"); 
         return null; 
    } 

    Bundle[] bundles = osgi.getBundles(); 

      
    for(int i=0;i<bundles.length;i++) { 
        Bundle bundle = bundles[i]; 

        if ( "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira".equals( bundle.getSymbolicName() ) ) { 

            BundleContext bctx = bundle.getBundleContext(); 
            ServiceReference[] refs = bctx.getAllServiceReferences(null,null); 
            if ( refs!=null ) { 
                for(int j=0; j<refs.length;j++) { 
                    Object prop = refs[j].getProperty("org.springframework.context.service.name"); 
                    if ( "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira".equals(prop) ) { 
                        return bctx.getService( refs[j] ); 
                    } 
                      
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

And it can be iterated like this:

```
            try { 
             
                ServiceOutcome<Collection<Sprint>> allSprints = getSprintManager().getAllSprints(); 
                sprints = allSprints.getValue(); 
                pages = sprints.size(); 
            } 
            catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Got an SearchException: " + e.getCause()); 
            }  

      for (Iterator iteratorSprints = sprints.iterator(); iteratorSprints.hasNext();) { 
                 
                Sprint sprint = (Sprint) iteratorSprints.next();
                //your code here
       }
```